# How Linux Loads Modules for Device Tree Nodes

Tags: kernel, driver, kernel-module, device-tree

I am reading linux and systemd source code to learn about the device tree mechanism and kernel module loading mechanism.
I learned that the bus-based device will be discoverd by the bus, and the device info will be send to the userspace in the way of uevent. Then the systemd will receive and process the module loading according to the udev rules.

Here comes my questions:

1. Device tree describs device, and the built-in device driver will be probed if the driver matches the of table. But, how is the modules loaded? Will the kernel send the info of the of table to the udevd or so?
2. How about ACPI? Since the ACPI table is presented to the kernel just like the device tree.

Any hint on which piece of code to check?

Edit: I think the device tree should be almost the same, the system should check the uevent or travel  through the sys fs for device information and then check module.alias and use rules to load the kennel. But I had not find the code of traveling the sys fs, so I have no idea how that is done...